# How to access config.php file of moodle in my php project

Tags: php, moodle

I want to include config.php file of moodle in my php project to access moodle database to retrieve courses.How can I access or include config.php file of moodle in my php project.Is it possible to access this file in my project.If not then suggest another way.

Comment: You mean , you want to connect your server database in Xamp or wamp server, n access it from xamp or wamp ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please clarify so that we can proceed.

Comment: I have moodle installed and it uses mysql database.
I have one another project.What i want is to fetch courses from moodle without using credentials.I want to use webservice.I have created a web service in moodle. and used http://www.rumours.co.nz/manuals/using_moodle_web_services.htm
this link.But i am getting this error 
"Check if user id exists and whether the web service account has capabilities required to execute core_user_get_users_by_id call". I have checked the user exists.